# Add XML nodes with Identity transform and then output to xhtml in a different template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm not sure if what I'm asking for is possible, but I need to first add two nodes into a parent XML node and then output the whole lot in xhtml using a different template.  I don't know how to get the result of the transform in to the second template.  I'm not entirely new to XSL but, I'm new to the Identity Transformations so this is likely above my pay grade.

Here's the example.

I have:

```
<metadata>
    <app><name>a</name></app>
    <app><name>b</name></app>
    <app><name>c</name></app>
</metadata>
```

I need to insert 2 more `<app>` nodes into `<metadata>` and so far I've used:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="metadata/app">
    <metadata>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <app><name>d</name></app>
        <app><name>e</name></app>
    <metadata>
</xsl:template>
```

Once the 2 new `<app>` nodes have been added, I need to output the newly transformed `<metadata>` as html using another template.  I assume I can use:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="app"><xsl:sort select="app/name" /></xsl:apply-templates>
```

I'm using a template here to get the nodes sorted but cause it's not always certain that the app/name nodes are in alphabetical order.

```
<xsl:template match="app">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

...but I don't know where or how to correctly get the new `<metadata>` into the last template using the apply-templates.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit for desired final html output (pretty simple):

```
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>b</h1>
<h1>c</h1>
<h1>d</h1>
<h1>e</h1>
```

Comment: Seeing the **final** output you expect to get out of the transformation would be helpful, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform two transformation steps in one XSLT 1.0 stylesheet then you need to use `exsl:node-set` or similar on a variable and you might need to use modes.

So define a global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="result1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="metadata"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

then you can use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($result1)/app"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="app">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

That simple sample does not require modes but as soon as you want to write template for the same match pattern for both steps you need to use modes to distinguish them.

Comment: This seems like the way to go, but for some reason `<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($result1)/app"/>` isn't getting into the app template.  If I just output the variable it appears to have the correct structure.  I might need to check into the modes but thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: If an XPath expression does not select anything then usually namespaces are the reason. Does your stylesheet do `xmlns="..."` somwhere up the tree? In that case put `xmlns=""` on the `xsl:variable`.

Comment: And you would need `xmlns=""` on the `xsl:template match="metadata"`

Comment: Just edited the identity transformation in the original question because the new `<app>` nodes weren't being added inside of metadata.  So with that change, I think the issue might be coming from having both `<xsl:copy-of select="metadata/app"/>` and `<xsl:template match="app">`.  Could that be the case?  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//
EN" indent="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have two transformations here? Without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve, as a suggestion, you could change your `app` matching template to also be a named template, taking in a parameter which defaults to `name`

```
<xsl:template match="app" name="outputApp">
    <xsl:param name="displayName" select="name" />
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="$displayName"/></h1>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Then, instead of creating new `app` elements, simply call the named template with a overriding value for the name parameter, like so

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="app">
        <xsl:sort select="app/name" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:call-template name="outputApp">
        <xsl:with-param name="displayName" select="'d'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="outputApp">
        <xsl:with-param name="displayName" select="'e'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Good thought.  As a point of clarification, I don't always know that the names d and e would be in the correct alphabetical order along with the names for the other app nodes.  That's why I'm trying to get the nodes added and then sorted before being output as html.